# Deleting in cascade with native query

Tags: java, orm, playframework, ebean, cascading-deletes

I have a Ebean Entity model with 3 entities related with @OneToMany relationships like this:

```
public class A extends Model {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    public Long id;

    public String name;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    public List<B> bList;
    ...
}

public class B extends Model {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    public Long id;

    public String name;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    public List<C> cList;
    ...
}

public class C extends Model {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    public Long id;

    public String name;

    ...
}
```

And I want to delete al Bs and Cs of a specific A object. I know that Ebean can take care of the deletion of Cs if I make something like this:

```
for (B b : a.bList) {
    b.delete();
}
```

but I don't think this is the best solution. I wanted to make something like this:

```
String sql = "DELETE FROM B WHERE B.a_id="+a.id;
SqlUpdate update = Ebean.createSqlUpdate(sql);
update.execute();
```

But it's a native SQL and it outputs a 'ConstraintViolationException' because it doesn't have an 'ON DELETE CASCADE'.

What would be the best solution?

Answer (score 0):

`com.avaje.ebean.Ebean` class has `delete` method which takes collection as argument:

```
static int delete(Collection<?> c) // Delete all the beans from a Collection.
```

So you can use following code:

```
Ebean.delete(a.bList);
a.bList = new ArrayList<B>();
```